# Split dataframe based on column header prefix and preserve additional desired columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe, split

Here is my dataframe:

```
df <- structure(list(contig = c("F26D10.3.1", "F26D10.3.1", "F26D10.3.1", 
"F26D10.3.1"), sample_name = structure(1:4, .Label = c("GLD4_2", 
"GLD4_3", "WT_1", "WT_2"), class = "factor"), group = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("GLD4", "WT"), class = "factor"), counts_C = c(90L, 
134L, 130L, 167L), hits_C = c(99, 147, 142, 174), counts_G = c(16L, 
34L, 28L, 35L), hits_G = c(16, 39, 32, 38), counts_U = c(904L, 
1150L, 1027L, 1602L), hits_U = c(1480, 1904, 1700, 2661)), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I want to split it into 2 dataframes, each containing 3 first columns followed by:

- all the remaining columns with names containing "counts_"
- all the remaining columns with names containing "hits_"

I am obtaining this by following code:

```
grouping_vars <- df[,1:3]

wanted <- sapply(c("counts_", "hits_"),
       function(x) df[startsWith(names(df),x)],
       simplify = FALSE)

df1 <- cbind(grouping_vars, wanted[1])
df2 <- cbind(grouping_vars, wanted[2])
```

However, this results in repeated header segments (e.g. hits_.hits_C). I can trim this, off course, but looking for more efficient way for the entire operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `split.default` by removing the substring from the column name into a `list` of data.frames and then append the first three columns

```
lapply(split.default(df[-(1:3)], sub("_.*", "", names(df)[-(1:3)])), 
     function(x) cbind(df[1:3], x))
```

-output

```
$counts
      contig sample_name group counts_C counts_G counts_U
1 F26D10.3.1      GLD4_2  GLD4       90       16      904
2 F26D10.3.1      GLD4_3  GLD4      134       34     1150
3 F26D10.3.1        WT_1    WT      130       28     1027
4 F26D10.3.1        WT_2    WT      167       35     1602

$hits
      contig sample_name group hits_C hits_G hits_U
1 F26D10.3.1      GLD4_2  GLD4     99     16   1480
2 F26D10.3.1      GLD4_3  GLD4    147     39   1904
3 F26D10.3.1        WT_1    WT    142     32   1700
4 F26D10.3.1        WT_2    WT    174     38   2661
```